# Scheduled Operation on Smart Contract

Tags: scheduling

Looking for a way to schedule an event within the smart contract. When the event is occurred should be able to invoke the method of the contract.

I want to implement this whole feature, within the smart contract itself an not by using some NodeJS API operation.

Comment: did you look at http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing will have a look. But looking more of a way to do it rather using a third party solution

Comment: Ethereum alarm clock in now defunct, have a look at [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it) for that. Basically you register for an oracle at a later time, pay a fee for that, and it will call your function on time. There is no way to do this internally.